# Struts 1.3 ActionForm - retrieving a collection from multiselect dropdown insted of using arrary

Tags: java, struct

What I cannot figure out is how to select multiple input from multielect drop down to my Action.By using a collections instead of array.I have posted the both jsp code and actionform.

This is my jsp:

```
<table class="table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="border: none;"><br><br><br><br><label class="control-label" >Grade</label></th>
                                                    <th style="border: none;">                                                        
                                                        <html:select name="GradeBoardConfigureForm" property="grade" multiple="">
                                                            <html:option value="">Grade List</html:option>
                                                            <html:optionsCollection  name="GradeBoardConfigureForm" property="gradelist" label="grade" value="gradeid"/>
                                                        </html:select>
                                                    </th>                         
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
```

FormBean:

```
public class GradeBoardConfigureForm extends ActionForm {

    private String board;
    private List grade;

    private List gradelist;
    private List boardlist;

    public String getBoard() {

        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(String board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

    public List getGradelist() {
        gradelist = new ArrayList<>();
        DAOFactory factory = HibernateDAOUtil.getDAOFactory();
        GradeDao gradedao = factory.getGradeDao();
        List<Academicgradeform> gradedaolist = gradedao.list();
        gradelist.addAll(gradedaolist);
        return gradelist;
    }

    public void setGradelist(List gradelist) {
        this.gradelist = gradelist;
    }



    public List getBoardlist() {
        boardlist = new ArrayList<>();
        DAOFactory factory = HibernateDAOUtil.getDAOFactory();
        BoardDao boarddao = factory.getBoardDAO();
        List<Academicboardform> boarddaolist = boarddao.list();
        boardlist.addAll(boarddaolist);
        return boardlist;
    }

    public void setBoardlist(List boardlist) {
        this.boardlist = boardlist;
    }

    public List getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(List grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not directly possible and is **not** Struts1 philosophy.

A form bean should only be a piece of code that helps to transfer data between the controller (a singleton, so it is stateless) and a view. It is not intended to be a domain object.

So your GradeBoardConfigureForm is a good example of you should **not** be done. You mix DAO in a form bean. It will be hard to write and hard to test and will lead to poorly structured code. And your problem *lays* here. If you had a domain object distinct from your form bean, the domain object would have a List, and the DAO layer whould bind the list to the database. And the controller (Action in stuts1) would copy the list to an Array in the form bean, pass it to the view, and in submit phase will use a populated Array according to your needs.

But I have 3 strong advices for you :

- Struts1 is deprecated (according to official [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) page), do not use it except for maintaining existing code - Struts2 or Spring MVC are current alternatives
- if you are a beginner, start by following existing tutorials
- before coding, carefully design your program structure. If you do not understand what I mean here, read (again if you already had a look at it) this document linked at the bottom of Apache strus1 page : [Understanding JavaServer Pages Model 2 architecture.](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-1999/jw-12-ssj-jspmvc.html)